# Google Play doesn't recognize my Genymotion device

Tags: google-play-store, genymotion

I run Android 4.4.4 in Genymotion. I [installed the Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/395857), which include Google Play. I logged into my Google account, and I see in the Google Play application on my phone that I'm logged in.

However, when I go to the Google Play on my computer's browser, it doesn't recognize my Android 4.4.4 in Genymotion device:

[image]

Is there any way to fix it, so that I can install applications Google Play on my computer's browser?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.